# Rotating Image in Android using matrix

Tags: android

i am trying to rotate an image(which is a circle) around 360 degree and while rotating the image if the rotationangle is 90 ,180,270 i need to change some text in the text view ,i m able to achieve the image rotation but i m not able to get the exact angles i.e. 90,180,270 while moving around it fast,

here is the git code for what i have done so far https://gist.github.com/2169073
,and here is an image to rotate https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kVaK.png please let me know how can i achieve the task

Comment: You want to move the arrow along with the drag ?

Comment: yes ,i actually need to change the text at exact angles 90,180,270

Comment: @rajesh.adhi i m able to drag the arrow though,but not able to change the text at angles when move faster around the image